# How to run node.js on normal linux hosting (cPanel)?

Tags: php, node.js, cpanel, ghost-blog

I recently saw a good blogging platform named [ghost](https://ghost.org/).
But it is based on `node.js` so a usual Linux hosting can't handle it.
So is it possible to run `node.js` on a Cpanel (Linux host) or convert node.js projects to normal php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DigitalOcean](http://www.digitalocean.com) is currently the cheapest and (in my opinion) the easiest way to start a Ghost blog. They offer one-click Ghost installations on their SSD VPSes, which run on Ubuntu. Hmm, DigitalOcean is quite new, they began back in 2011, but are setting new standards - for $5 /month, you can get a VPS with 20Gb SSD, 1TB bandwidth and other cool features...

But beware, they're so cheap because they don't offer 24/7 support, like Mediatemple or other enterprise hosting solutions, but they *do* have an amazing community-driven forum/blog, where you can find nice tutorials, ranging from how to set up a VPS to hosting OpenVPN.

Answer (score 1):

Usually normal shared hosts do not provide node.js hosting. You can try aws ec2 and install node.js in it or try heroku or other node.js hosting providers.

Comment: these services are good but this not answers my question.what about convert?

Comment: Answer would be, Node.js will not run on normal linux hosting which doesnot have node.js installed in their server. This implies to almost all of the shared hosting providers that are used to provide php/mysql hosting. May be they will soon be able to provide Node.js hosting like they provide for ruby. there are not any automated converter for node.js projects to php. You may need to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Regular shared hosts don't support nodejs but you can try a private server like aws or specific nodejs hosting like www.nodejitsu.com

Answer (score 1):

Yalamber answered the question as I would have.

I'm not sure if this applied when Nick wrote his answer, but IMO the cheapest and easiest way to set up a Ghost blog is via Ghost's Hosted Platform: https://ghost.org/subscribe/trial/